# Tox run shell command and get correct exit code

Tags: python, pylint, tox

I have the following tox.ini file to run pylint.

It grabs all python files and then lints them.

```
[testenv:pylint]
deps =
  -rrequirements.txt
basepython=python2
commands =
  - sh -c 'find . -iname "*.py" | grep -v .tox | xargs pylint -sn --output-format=colorized --rcfile={toxinidir}/.pylintrc'
```

Running just the shell portion on the command line has the correct exit code.

However when running using tox, it swallows the exit code and is always successful.

Is there anyway for tox to have the correct exit code while using the `sh -c` option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting a command with a single dash character means ignore the exit code. <sup>[[1]](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/basic.html#ignoring-a-command-exit-code)</sup>

```
commands =
  sh -c 'find . -iname "*.py" | grep -v .tox | xargs pylint -sn --output-format=colorized --rcfile={toxinidir}/.pylintrc'
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that. Thank you!